# Implementing user-based security in Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When logging into my application as user, I want said user to have access to their own particular maintenance records. Presumably, this would be done using the UID that is generated once the user has signed up to the application using Firebase Auth.

**MaintenanceActivity**

```
   private boolean updateMaintenance(String title, String desc, String id, String primary, String secondary, String property) {

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance").child(id);
        Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance (id, title, desc, primary, secondary, property);

        databaseReference.setValue(maintenance);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Updated Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    private void addMaintenance(){

        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        String primary = spinnerPrimary.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String secondary = spinnerSecondary.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)){

            String id = databaseMaintenance.push().getKey();

            Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance (id, title, desc, primary, secondary, property);

            databaseMaintenance.child(id).setValue(maintenance);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a maintenance record", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

**LoginActivity**

This is what I have implemented at the moment. Currently, I can log in using the Firebase-stored credentials, however, the maintenance records that are held in the Firebase database always shown. No matter who is logged in.

```
Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

**Database Rules**

I have set my database rules up as follows:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Current Firebase Database**

These are the maintenance cases that are showing when logged in as any user.

[image]

Not sure if my MaintenanceActivity code is required here and, if so, which parts.

Any help on this would be massively appreciated, have been stuck on this for so long now.

Many thanks.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't read from the Firebase Database, so it's going to be hard to say what's going on with your rules and data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What do you require? I’m conscious of clogging up the question with lines and lines of code.

Comment: To be honest your question is unclear to me. But from scanning it seems that you have a problem read from or writing to the database. If that's indeed the problem, then edit your question to include the minimal reading/writing code that gives problems. To minimize the code, but still be complete, have a look at [creating an minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticated users accessing their data using Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282509/authenticated-users-accessing-their-data-using-firebase-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

To fetch only logged in user records in firebase ..

First add security rules in Firebase console.

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /maitenance/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
```

Then, you need to add user id node as child of maintenance node, user maintenance records should be children of the logged in user id node.

Finally, in the read operation pass user id to fetch maintenance records of user id.

```
  firestoreDB.collection("maintenance")
            .whereEqualTo("userId", userId)
        .get()
```

Please see how [user specific data is saved in and fetched from firestore database](http://www.zoftino.com/firebase-cloud-storage-upload-download-delete-files-android-example). You can do same with realtime database as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. The link provided also is useful too, thanks.  However, I'm not sure where to implement this in my SignUp/Login/MaintenanceActivities. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: At the point where you are trying to add maintenance data to firebase db for add part and for read part where you are retrieving the data.

Comment: I have added two of my methods from `MaintenanceActivity`. When I tried to put the answer in there were errors in the code. Will there not need to be something implemented in the `SignUp` and `Login` activities also?

Comment: Apologies if it looks like I'm fishing for answers, however, I am super stuck. Need help badly!

Comment: get user id by using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() and add that db.